# Cannot Add Drivers to Windows 2016 Server Core - Operation Not Supported

Tags: windows-server-2016, print-server

When trying to add the default "RICOH Class Driver", I am stopped by the error "This operation is not supported."
In fact, while the Ricoh driver is the one that I want, I receive the same error no matter which driver I try to add.

How am I supposed to add this driver to Windows Server 2016 Core?
I am currently interacting through the Print Management tool from Windows 10. Both the server and the client are joined to the same redacted domain.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the printer shared?  I've run into this error message when trying to update the driver on a printer that's currently shared.  The workaround is to unshare the printer, update the driver, and then reshare it.  You know, assuming you have to share it and can't exorcise it, purge it with fire, or otherwise rid your environment of the unmitigated evil that is a printer.

Comment: The printer is not shared. The printer does not exist yet. I am seeking to make the printer exist, but a printer cannot exist without drivers. The drivers cannot be added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not like this answer because it is stupid. However, it is a stupid as the problem.

Removing and re-adding the role has fixed the issue.
No restart was required, though I did restart the machine prior removing and re-adding the role.

Comment: Wow. Had the same exact problem and your solution worked. Thanks, Microsoft!

Answer (score 1):

very old threat. But maybe helpful for some people. For me only restarting print spooler solved the problem, which is much easier to do than re-adding a role in Windows